# Variable doesn't store what given to it - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm having trouble with storing a date that I got from SQLite DB into a `Date` Var, I'm trying to save the date coming from DB to the `ResultTask.AlarmDate` after converting it from String to Date.

When I tried and deleted the `?` from `ResultTask.AlarmDate?` it stored the data fine, but when I have a task without an alarm I get an error cause I want to store `nil` it the var when there's no alarm, and tried multiple other ways to fix it but nothing work.

I made a break point right after the issue and used the `Console` to see the data and got confused, cause the data shown when I print what I'm trying to store in the var but the var is still `nil`, all shown below.

**Notes**

The code that getting data from DB works fine, I'm using the Objective-C FM-Database library, and result is seen in the `Console` below.

the `.toDate()` is an extension for `String` that I use and it code is in `AppDelegate.swift` as seen bellow, and it work just fine.

the `Task` Variable type is something I made in a `Task.swift` file to easy the work, and it work just fine & shown below.

**The Function:**

```
func GetTasks() -> [Task]{
        var Tasks : [Task] = [Task]()

        let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)
        let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
        databasePath = (docsDir + "/" + "Tasks.db") as NSString

        let TaskRecorderDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
        if (TaskRecorderDB?.open())! {
            let querySQL = "Select * from 'Tasks' ORDER BY Priority DESC"
            let results:FMResultSet? = TaskRecorderDB?.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsIn: nil)

            while results!.next() {
                var ResultTask : Task! = Task()
                ResultTask.ID = Int((results?.int(forColumn: "ID"))!)
                ResultTask.FileName = results?.string(forColumn: "FileName")
                ResultTask.Name = results?.string(forColumn: "Name")
                ResultTask.Categorie = Int((results?.int(forColumn: "Categorie"))!)
                ResultTask.Priority = Int((results?.int(forColumn: "Priority"))!)
                ResultTask.AlarmDate? = (results?.string(forColumn: "Alarm").toDate())!
                //Break point
                ResultTask.Repeat? = (results?.string(forColumn: "Repeat"))!
                ResultTask.Completed = Int((results?.int(forColumn: "Completed"))!).toBool()

                if(ResultTask.Completed == false){
                    Tasks.append(ResultTask)
                }
                ResultTask = nil
            }

            TaskRecorderDB?.close()
        } else {
            print("Error #DB06: \(TaskRecorderDB?.lastErrorMessage())")
        }

        return Tasks
    }
```

**Console:**

```
(lldb) print (results?.string(forColumn: "Alarm").toDate())!
(Date) $R0 = 2016-11-23 17:21:00 UTC
(lldb) print ResultTask.AlarmDate
(Date?) $R1 = nil
(lldb)
```

**AppDelegate.swift:**

```
extension String {
    func toDate () ->Date! {
        var FinalDate : Date! = nil
        if (self != ""){
            let DateFormatter : Foundation.DateFormatter = Foundation.DateFormatter()
            DateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
            DateFormatter.dateFormat = "y-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"
            FinalDate = DateFormatter.date(from: self)!
        }

        return FinalDate
    }
}
```

**Task.swift:**

```
import Foundation

class Task : NSObject {
    var ID : Int! = nil
    var FileName : String! = nil
    var Name : String! = nil
    var Categorie : Int! = nil
    var Priority : Int! = nil
    var AlarmDate : Date! = nil
    var Repeat : String! = nil
    var Expired : Bool! = nil
    var Completed : Bool! = nil
}
```

***Thanks in advance.***

**Edit for @KaraBenNemsi :**

I updates the `.toDate()` as you said.

& in task I used `var AlarmDate : Date?` instead of `var AlarmDate : Date! = nil` (I didn't use you're other tip in `Task.swift` for now cause I'll need to change a lot of other code in the app).

And used  `ResultTask.AlarmDate = results?.string(forColumn: "Alarm").toDate()` and I get a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` in it when the task doesn't have an alarm.

Comment: I highly recommend to clean up the (partially contradictory) mess of question and exclamation marks. If a property is supposed to have a value treat it as non-optional, otherwise as real optional. Properties declared as implicit unwrapped optional are the worst compromise.

Comment: @vadian I'm not good at it and I hate it and it gives me headache. But I played with it a lot and did a lot of situations with it but mostly it gave me error and I can't run the app, or it work but not like what I want.

Comment: So as I understand it still crashes at this line `ResultTask.AlarmDate = results?.string(forColumn: "Alarm").toDate()`. Could you please post the code of `string(forColumn: String)` function?

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi it's not mine its from the [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) library that I use

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAlattas are you sure you left out the `!`at the end of this line `ResultTask.AlarmDate = results?.string(forColumn: "Alarm").toDate()`. Could you please try this line `ResultTask.AlarmDate = results?.string(forColumn: "Alarm")?.toDate()`

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi It Worked!! using `ResultTask.AlarmDate = results?.string(forColumn: "Alarm")?.toDate()`  Finally, thank you. change your answer and ill mark it.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAlattas You are welcome! I updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change this line in the task class since it can be optional

from this

```
var AlarmDate: Date! = nil
```

to this

```
var AlarmDate: Date?
```

And then use this line to set the alarm

```
ResultTask.AlarmDate = results?.string(forColumn: "Alarm")?.toDate()
```

Also variable names should usually start with a lowercase letter.

I also think this line is unnecessary. You can just omit that line.

```
ResultTask = nil
```

Please also change the extension to

```
extension String {
func toDate() -> Date? {
    guard self != "" else {
         return nil
    }
    var finalDate: Date?
    let DateFormatter : Foundation.DateFormatter = Foundation.DateFormatter()
    DateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    DateFormatter.dateFormat = "y-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"
    finalDate = DateFormatter.date(from: self)
    return finalDate
   }
}
```

And maybe try to get more into how optionals work 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Addition: 
Your class task should probably also look more like below. But then you have to change code in other places as well. It also forces you to pass all the required parameters in the constructor when initialising the task object.

```
class Task {
    var id: Int
    var fileName: String
    var name: String
    var category: Int
    var priority: Int
    var alarmDate: Date?
    var repeating: String
    var expired: Bool
    var completed: Bool

     init(id: Int, fileName: String, name: String, category: Int, priority: Int, repeating: String, expired: Bool, completed: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.fileName = fileName
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.priority = priority
        self.repeating = repeating
        self.expired = expired
        self.completed = completed
    }
}
```

And here is also a link to a Swift style guide:

https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Comment: it work when theres an alarm, but when the task doesnt have an alarm it give me the `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error.

Comment: I want the var to be nil when there isn't an alarm

Comment: with the above code the var AlarmDate of the object AlarmDate will be nil if no date is set

Comment: In this line `ResultTask.AlarmDate = results?.string(forColumn: "Alarm").toDate()`, but without the ? mark it can't be nil, right? I want it nil when theres no alarm.

Comment: I get a error in the guard line `expect 'else' after 'guard' condition` but it still run!

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAlattas sorry forgot the else  -> updated my answer

Comment: no problem, I read about the guard it's a new thing for me and now its work, thanks

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAlattas You are welcome! I also added some more hints to my answer.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAlattas could you please mark my answer as correct? thank you!

Comment: I still get the `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error when the task doesn't have an alarm

Comment: In which line? could you please update your answer to reflect any changes you made

Answer (score 0):

Change your task to have this

```
var AlarmDate : Date?
```

And then do this

```
if let alarm = results?.string(forColumn: "Alarm").toDate() {
    ResultTask.AlarmDate = alarm
}
```

If any nil is found while unwrapping results, you won't set the value of ResultTask.AlarmDate.

Comment: Sorry @KaraBenNemsi, I just thought I could help a little with the if-let. With your update for the toDate() function (which didn't exist by the time I answered), things will work.

Comment: no problem ;-) @JeanSandrin bad timing. But the questioner needs to brush up on optionals anyway

Comment: Yeah, couldn't agree more. I would just say that you should update your answer with a link to learn more about optionals, but you already did ;)

Comment: work when theres an alarm, when there isn't I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error in the `if let alarm = results?.string(forColumn: "Alarm").toDate() {` line

I tried `if (results?.string(forColumn: "Alarm").toDate() != nil) {` still same

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAlattas please see my updated answer and update your toDate() function